# My ResultSet will only print first row

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a ResultSet that I know contains 8 rows of data because I checked it with a direct query of the DB. My code will only display the first row.

If anyone can give me some help I would greatly appreciate it. The first row is what should I expect it to be, I just don't know how to get it to move on to print subsequent rows.

```
term= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);        
// Select a list of the surveys that fall under the term    
query= "Select cid,subject,course_number,instructor_id from Courses where term=" + Integer.parseInt(args[1]);    
result = statement.executeQuery(query);
                String query2="";
                while(result.next())
                {
                    // Pull in the data
                    cid = result.getInt("cid");
                    subject = result.getString("subject");
                    courseNumber= result.getInt("course_number");
                    instructorId= result.getInt("instructor_id");enter code here

                    // Get the instructors last name
                    query2= "Select last_name from Instructors where fid=" + instructorId;

                    subResult= statement.executeQuery(query2);
                    while(subResult.next())
                    {
                        instructorLName= subResult.getString(1);
                    }

                    // Get the averages and num submitted
                    query2= "Select num_submitted, sum_q1, sum_q2, sum_q3, sum_q4, survey_id from surveys where cid=" + cid;
                    subResult= statement.executeQuery(query2);
                    while(subResult.next())
                    {
                        numSub= subResult.getInt(1);
                        sumQ1= subResult.getInt(2);
                        sumQ2= subResult.getInt(3);
                        sumQ3= subResult.getInt(4);
                        sumQ4= subResult.getInt(5);
                        surveyId= subResult.getInt(6);
                    }

                    // Print everything necessary
                    System.out.println( surveyId + " " + term + " " + subject + " " + courseNumber +
                    " " + instructorLName + " " + sumQ1/numSub + " " + sumQ2/numSub + " " + sumQ3/numSub
                    + " " + sumQ4/numSub);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you should do all this processing in query if possible  and return result. Can you please specify table structure and data. I think your where criteria is such that it returns 1 row but as you said you already tried so please specify value of where criteria also

Comment: Not a good idea to reuse the ResultSet subResult without closing with query2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but the problem might be that you are using same Statement object to execute different queries. Create separate statement instances for query and query2 and try.